# To find minimum value of an equation

Tags: number-theory

Find minimum value of $\sqrt{(a-p)^2 + (4-a-q)^2}$. Given $p^2 + q^2=1$.

My attempts

1. I tried putting $p= \sin¢$ and $q = \cos ¢$ but in the end I got an equation with $\sin$ and $a$ which I couldn't solve further.
2. I tried to think of it as distance formula with one pt. being $(p,q)$ lying on a circle and another point $(a, a-4)$ which is on a line $x-y=4$ so I plotted it and I got the answer as $2√2-1$. Is it correct?

Comment: Is $a$ a fixed value, or is it also variable?

Comment: a is a variable

Comment: $(a-p)^2+(4-a-q)^2 = a^2-2ap+p^2+(4-a)^2-2(4-a)q+q^2= a^2-2ap+(4-a)^2-2(4-a)q+1= ...$, does this help?

Comment: @HarshitaJain: The point must not be $$(a,4-a)$$? and the line $x+y=4$?

Comment: +1 to your posting.  Your analysis is accurate, valid and elegant.  The closest point of form $~(a,4-a)~$ to the circle occurs at $~a=2,~$ and the closest point of intersection of this point to the circle is with point $~(x,y) = \displaystyle \left( ~\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, ~\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ~\right).~$ The distance is $~\displaystyle \sqrt{2 \times \left[ ~2 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ~\right]^2}.~$ This equals $~\displaystyle \sqrt{2} \times \left[ ~2 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ~\right] = \left[ ~2\sqrt{2} - 1 ~\right].$

Comment: @Khosrotash It doesn't matter we get the same answer even if we take that line.

Answer (score 2):

The distance required is exactly the distance between $(p,q)$ and $(a,4-a)$.
Since $(p,q)$ is on the unit circle with centre $(0,0)$, therefore the minimum value of $\sqrt{(a-p)^2 + (4-a-q)^2}$ is the shortest distance between the circle and line $y=4-x$ and equal to
$$\frac{|0+0-4|}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2}}-1=2\sqrt 2-1  .$$